# How to separate objects by colour matlab

Tags: matlab

I want the Matlab to recognize colors and analyse the object if it yellow otherwise it would ignore it.
I know how to analyze the objects but I don't know how to eliminate the other non-yellow ones

Comment: How far did you get? Successfully created a binary mask of the yellow objects? What do you mean with "eliminating"? Change to black?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple approach that I can come up with is this quick and dirty program:

```
i = imread('school_zone.jpg');
r = i(:,:,1);
g = i(:,:,2);
b = i(:,:,3);

threshold = 100;

isyellow = r > threshold & g > threshold & b < threshold;
```

(`b < threshold` to prevent the white to be confused with yellow)

```
imshow(isyellow);
```

[image: sample image]

[image: yellow mask]

Comment: (One can use different thresholds for R, G and B.)